# From where should i start to properly get the concept of ORM

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, orm

So I have been using an ORM for the past 3-4 months and have developed a website using it in par with a framework.

My curiosity is grown larger and what ORM really are, so i decided to start building one from scratch but did some research yesterday and today and im still very confused on where to start from and I don't seem to be able to find a good guide to start from.

Lately my love for MongoDB has been growing so it would be even more fun and interesting if I can have php + MongoDB ORM.

Do you guys have any starting points? Like books, slides or articles where I can have a look at and start.

If you guys want to add anything please tell me! I really want to learn the deep end of a infrastructure of a website!

Comment: Im more of a practical person id rather workon something then just read on it. Same thing as a car you drive but don't know how the internal work.

Comment: Well, he's used to the interface the ORM exposes, if you would take that same interface and try to implement it, it can be very informative.

Comment: Just recently I started wondering HOW a router works in PHP.  I've used both CodeIgnitor and Laravel, and while I knew how to use the specific routers that they have, I didn't know how they worked until I started building my own, and started actually following the data as it traveled through one.

Answer (score 2):

With multiple different implementations of ORM's in different languages, it always comes down to a few different patterns which can be interesting to look into.

A few patterns are the `ActiveRecord` which are objects containing the data for each row, and are responsible for saving themselfs.
And `Repository` which seperates the actual models from the repository.

[Active Records vs. Repository - pros and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522009/active-records-vs-repository-pros-and-cons)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern

If you want to learn about programming architectures, I would highly recommend the following book with accompanied website

http://martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/